# How can I pass a Controller in as a dependency?

Tags: dependency-injection, sapui5

I'm looking to create a test file (test.js). The Test.js file's purpose will be to perform unit tests for a particular controller (ie: Main.controller.js).

How can I load in this controller to an external js file?

I've tried using sap.require:

```
sap.ui.require(["/pricingTool/Controller/Main.controller"],

 function(Main){
     //Quint code
     test("hello test", function(assert) {
      assert.ok(1 == "1", "Passed!");
    });
});
```

But I get an error that says:

*failed to load /Controller/Main.controller.js*

This tells me I'm either structuring this wrong, using the wrong path, or both. Any suggestions would be helpful. I've attached my file tree below for reference.

[image]

**Component.js**

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/core/UIComponent'],
    function(UIComponent) {
    "use strict";

    var Component = UIComponent.extend("pricingTool.Component", {

        metadata : {

            metadata : {
                maniest: "json"
            },
            rootView : "pricingTool.view.Main",
            dependencies : {
                libs : [
                    "sap.m",
                    "sap.ui.layout"
                ]
            },
            config : {
                sample : {
                    files : [
                        "Main.view.xml",
                        "Main.controller.js"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        init : function () {
            // call the init function of the parent
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
            // additional initialization can be done here
        }
    });

    return Component;

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Pricing Tool</title>

        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" 
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"pricingTool": "./"}'>
        </script>
        <script src='../pdfmake-master/build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../pdfmake-master/build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>

        <!-- Application launch configuration -->
        <script>

            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
                new sap.m.App ({
                    pages: [
                        new sap.m.Page({
                            title: "Pricing Tool Rapid Prototype", 
                            enableScrolling : true,
                            content: [ new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                                name : "pricingTool"
                            })]
                        })
                    ]
                }).placeAt("content");
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <!-- UI Content -->
    <body class="sapUiBody" id="content" role="application">
    </body>

</html>
```

**initialTest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.css">
      <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js">
      </script>    
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.js"></script>
      <script src="allTests.js"></script>
      <script src="/Controller/Main.controller.js"></script>          
      <script>
      </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you used any namespace ? Can you send me your bootstrap ? Also, if you are using component, then all paths are defined relative to Component.js file.

Comment: yes, would you like to open a chat? Also I am utilizing the component js. I will include that code above

Comment: Can you try : `sap.ui.require(["pricingTool/Controller/Main.controller"]` instead of `sap.ui.require(["/pricingTool/Controller/Main.controller"]`  ? ( removing the front-splash ( / )

Comment: Already did same result

Comment: in initialtest.html the path to the controller is wrong : <script src="/Controller/Main.controller.js"></script>  >>>> <script src="../Controller/Main.controller.js"></script>

Comment: Hi Ash, I tried that, still getting the same Error

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reference the controller file directly inside the .html file.

The problem is that UI5 does not know where to find your resources. The resolution process is the following:

- All standard resources are loaded from a path relative to where your `sap-ui-core.js` was loaded from.
- All resources with custom namespaces are loaded based on the resource roots definition.

Basically, in the resource roots you define a map between a namespace prefix and the location where to find the resources starting with that prefix. If you use relative paths, then the locations are resolved relative to your html file.

In your `index.html` you have done this: `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"pricingTool": "./"}'` which is perfectly fine. Because your index.thml is located at the root of the project, requesting the `pricingTool/Controller/Main.controller` will lead to making a request at `./Controller/Main.controller` which is actually our file.

But in your `initialTest.html` you failed to specify any resource root at all. Moreover, you referenced your controller directly and the path seems to not be right (note that a path starting with a leading `/` is considered an absolute path on the current host; depending on the server you are using, this might not be correct, as usually each application has its own subpath in the server).

You should therefore include a `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"pricingTool": "../"}'` inside your `initialTest.html`. Notice that I have used `..` because the html file is inside the `Test` folder (and the other stuff is in sibling folders).